# How can add non English characters in Mysql Using php

Tags: php, mysql

I can insert some non English languages (indian languages) such as hindi malayalam etc.It display properly in PHPMYADMIN page. But when I open my webpage it appear as question mark. How can I fix this error .. I tried the old answer which marked as duplicate but which is not working properly

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: use `utf8` as page encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a different encoding/charset for your DB-table than what your website. Setup the encoding of your tables with the same charset you have in your html-header like this (exchange utf-8 with what you need)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```